# Extract SVG file element with PHP

Tags: php, svg

I want to extract image tag from svg file, and replace the image path with only file name with PHP. Have generated with SVG with fabric.js canvas.

Here is my svg file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="165" height="265" xml:space="preserve">
    <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.1.4</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g transform="translate(84.5 63) scale(1.93 1)">
        <text font-family="'Droid Sans'" font-size="24" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: rgb(161,161,161); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-20 23)">
            <tspan x="0" y="-15.6" fill="rgb(161,161,161)">test</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(82.5 150) scale(0.11 0.09)">
        <image xlink:href="http://localhost/magento191/web/media/toolclipartupload/arrow3.png" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: 000000; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-726 -726)" width="1452" height="1452"></image>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I haven't tried until, but Is it possible to get image tag from svg file or from svg data in a parameter?

Comment: @PranavPatel svg is just an XML , you can parse it and get what ever data you need.Do you want to put PHP into SVG files ?

Comment: @CodingAnt, thanks for your reply, but what i want to achieve, with PHP, i want to read this xml, image tag <image xlink:href="http://localhost/magento191/web/media/toolclipartupload/arrow3.png" , i want to make it <image xlink:href="arrow3.png" > and write this line into svg file, so is there any syntax so i can get image tag from entire file and replace the path

Comment: @pranav may be you can use REGEX for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done that with

```
$flag = preg_match_all('`image xlink:href="([^"]*)"`', $svgfile, $output_array);
```

Thanks you all the CHAMPS for your time... :)